# Web API controller with custom name trigger error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I'm a beginner with Web API. So I created a simple function test like this.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/[controller]/test")]
    public string[] test()
    {
        return new string[] { "test1","test2" };
    }
```

Here I created a custom method test with route specification. But when I try **https://localhost:44389/api/values/test**, it says `{"errors":{"id":["The value 'test' is not valid."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"8000001f-0002-e900-b63f-84710c7967bb"}`

Plese tell me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the slash prefix if you want to ignore the route on controller:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]/test")]
```

Otherwise your route will be something like `/api/values/api/values/test`.